# macOS Sierra changing color profiles at startup

Tags: display, macos, bug, color

I have seen this issue discussed for previous macOS iterations, but there never seems to be a solution.

I have yet to find much discussion for Sierra and I am getting quite frustrated. I run a digitization lab (we work with archival materials) and our workstations are all Macs.

We have used **ColorMunki** to create custom profiles for all our screens for years, but now that we have upgraded the computers to Sierra, we're having an issue. ColorMunki still operates perfectly fine, but every time a computer is turned on, it fails to select the correct profile at startup and comes up horribly blue.

And it's not that the system does not remember my selection - if I go to `System Preferences -> Displays -> Color`, it suddenly jumps to the correct profile without clicking anything else and will stay selected, to my knowledge, until the computer is restarted again.

**Night Shift** is not on, and I have tried deleting what extraneous profiles I can, but it seems to do nothing. This is happening to several different computers, so it's not an isolated issue.

Anyone know anything?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-install the software.

Please follow these steps:

1. Backup your current color profile.
2. Uninstall the X-Rite ColorMunki software.
3. Restart your Mac.
4. Re-Install the X-Rite software.
5. Install the [X-Rite device manager](http://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?ID=1470&Action=Support&SoftwareID=1582&catid=109).
6. Create a new color profile or import your backed up profile.
7. Restart your Mac to check for the previous issue.

Did this answer help?